# SMS syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Tags: php

I'm trying to set up sending sms from our pbx but i keep getting a syntax error on the $data line.  If tried as is and with echo but the text never gets sent.  Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?  Thanks!!!

// Get the call data from PBX
    $call_ani = $_POST['call_ani'];

```
$url = 'http://api.messaging.test.sms.net

$data="botkey=123456&apimethod=send&msg=HelloWorld&user='call_ani'&network=SMS&from=1111111111";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'User:Password');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
print "ERROR ". curl_error($ch) ."\n<br/>";
}
curl_close($ch);
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to close the first string.

Change:

```
$url = 'http://api.messaging.test.sms.net
```

To:

```
$url = 'http://api.messaging.test.sms.net';
```

Comment: God I feel stupid, been going since 3am.  Time for a break.  Thanks for the heads up!!!

Answer (score 0):

The very first line is missing an ending:

```
$url = 'http://api.messaging.test.sms.net
```

Change to:

```
$url = 'http://api.messaging.test.sms.net';
```